# AWS ECS Task Definition environment variable using private ip parameter

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, mern, cicd

I have a simple MVP style fullstack MERN app deployed using 3x services / 3x tasks on a single t2.micro SPOT instance.

Challenge: Every time the SPOT instance is replaced, the private IP changes.

Workaround: The env variable for the backend needs to be updated with DB_HOST such that it can connect to the database task hosted on the same ec2 SPOT instance.

Requirement: Is there a way to pass in the ec2 SPOT container instances private IP as a parameter to the Env variable such that if it changes, the DB_HOST env variable in the backend task definition is automagically updated?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IP address using instance [metadata](https://curl%20http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname). There is also ECS metadata for containers. If you need this an environment variable you will need to run a script before running your application.

There probably isn't really any good reason for any part of anything to depend on a private ip address. If you want to access this instance in a reliable way, you would use a load balancer, target group, etc. If this is used to host containers on ECS, you would create a Service. Maybe you would use App Mesh.

This is for the exact reason you are experiencing in that the instance can stop and start which will give it a new ip address. This can happen for reasons outside of your control, such as a hardware failure.

In general when you are just getting something up and running you might use this private ip address you have. But once things progress past that and you need this ip address in other places it's best to do things righrt.

Comment: Thank you so much @Derrops and agree with the reasons for having a Network load balancer + route53 DNS to abstract the underlying ec2 private ips although my use case is MVP on a single ec2 instance. I am already paying for an application load balancer to achieve ACM/HTTPS endpoint and dont want to pay for another LB. I can very simply deploy my 3-tier containerised MERN app to a single ec2 (t2.micro) using "git clone/pull" and "make run / docker-compose up -d" although am trying to implement CI/CD using GitHub actions > AWS ECR > AWS ECS.

Comment: Rather use ecs than running docker commands on an ec2 box. Maybe checkout beanstalk or something to get going quickly. We have the following setup API GW ->  NLB -> ECS running in private Subnet.